# Stellar Asset Scanning

Tags: assets

Is there a way to scan or list all assets in Stellar ?
I use JavaScript SDK and have used the class Asset but this is helpful only when I know the asset name or asset issuer address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [Server.assets](https://stellar.github.io/js-stellar-sdk/Server.html#assets), which is designed to interface the [assets endpoint](https://www.stellar.org/developers/horizon/reference/endpoints/assets-all.html).